# Se desea Implementar un algoritmo recursivo para realizar la suma de los Elementos de una matriz n*n utilizando "Divide y Venceras"

Tags: java

Sabiendo que tenemos una matriz de N*N, Tenemos que utilizar el método de Divide y Vencerás para Poder sumar los elementos de la matriz y además tiene que usarse de forma recursiva.
Actualmente tengo mi código de esta forma:

```java
public static int MatrizDyV(int ini, int fin, int [][] matriz){
         
         if(ini==fin) {
             return matriz[ini][fin];
         }else {
             int mitad =(ini+fin)/2;
             int x = MatrizDyV(ini, mitad, matriz);
             int y = MatrizDyV(mitad+1,fin, matriz);
             
             return x+y;
         } 
            }
```

Pero al pasarle: `int Matriz  [2][2] = {{2,2},{3,5}}`
Me lanza un error.

Comment: Considera colocar en tu pregunta lo que has avanzado de tu código. Te invito a revisar [ask]

Comment: @JeanGotopo gracias

Comment: Cuál es el error?